Show all boot messages over serial port (and potentially disable HDMI)
I am using this in config.txt (RPI Zero 2W, bullseye)
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait disable_splash=1 logo.nologo

This prints just fine some early messages
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.1.21-v7+ (dom@buildbot) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0
[    0.000000] random: crng init done
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0bc00000, size 256 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001bffffff]
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s36884 r8192 d24556 u69632
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113680
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=0 video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:1C:A1:34 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait disable_splash=1 logo.nologo
[    0.000000] Unknown kernel command line parameters "disable_splash=1", will be passed to user space.
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 173812K/458752K available (10240K kernel code, 1452K rwdata, 2900K rodata, 1024K init, 613K bss, 22796K reserved, 262144K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 34800 entries in 103 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 102 pages with 4 groups
[    0.000000] trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.

However, after this
[    8.344671] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    8.369395] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    8.394875] systemd[1]: Finished Restore / save the current clock.
[    8.420450] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.

Nothing is printed until login.
All the services are printed over HDMI.
Any idea how to capture all over serial port and potentially disable HDMI completely?
Thanks in advance,

I don't know where you got that rubbish you listed but it has nothing to do with any valid config.txt and is obsolete even in cmdline.txt. If you seriously want to change use raspi-config.

You should start simple, after you've read the documentation.
